# In UltraVNC, what do the green and red rectangles indicate?

Tags: windows, vnc, ultravnc

[image]

**What do the green (on here) and the red light (off here) indicate?**

Did not find any reference to this on the [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) website.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send/Receive data I believe.  Green light indicates packets are being received by the client, red indicates the client is sending packets.

Comment: thanks! Can you please point to where you read about this, if anywhere?

Comment: the red one seldom (almost never) blinks. But the client should be sending about the same number of packets as it is receiving, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Lazer - I don't recall, I think it is an old convention.  I did find reference to the green "receive light" on the UltraVNC forums too.  The way to test the red light i would imagine is to see if it lights when you type or click.  You really only expect to SEND when you are inputting into the remote.

Comment: Here's and answer from the ultravnc forums: http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?p=54470